# run ssh to execute a ruby script with params

Tags: ruby, ssh

It seems that I'm able to execute the script without params, but when I want to add params to the ruby script this is not possible for me. My current approach looks like this:

```
ssh user@host 'cd app/path'; 'ruby' < test.rb 

ssh user@host 'cd app/path'; 'ruby' < test.rb with_params
```

But it results in an error: (No such file or directory)

Has somebody a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You want to add the parameters to the `ruby`, not to the standard input (after `<`. This should do the job:

```
ssh user@host 'cd app/path; ruby -- with_params' < test.rb
```

Otherwise, it would be better to copy the file to remote host and run it directly from there (if you have proper execution bit and shebang):

```
scp test.rb user@host:app/path
ssh user@host 'cd app/path; test.rb with_params'
```